# Can you go from pkh -> address using the CLI?

Tags: cardano-cli

Let's say I have a public key hash, is it possible to get the address corresponding to that hash using the CLI?

Comment: An address is made of of 3 components: Network + Payment Credentials/ Validator Credentials + Optional Staking Credentials (can be StakeValidator Hash or StakingKeys).

Answer (score 2):

No, as that would sort of defeat the purpose of having a key hash in the first place (Hashing is, by definition, a one-way operation). Also, addresses can be built using different combinations of payment and staking keys, so a single key hash can be indicative of a key with ownership over multiple addresses.

Comment: In the question it is assumed that we have an pubkeyhash. If we look at the defenition of an address it consists of a credential and maybe a stakingcredential. The former is in the case of a normal shelley address given by a pubkeyHash. If it is a script, then its the validator hash. So it is definitly possible to construct an address from a pubkeyhash. What is not possible is deriving the pubkey from the pubkeyhash (as you state). See https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger/html/Ledger-Address.html#t:Address

Answer (score 0):

You might want to investigate [cardano-serialization-lib](https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib/blob/master/example/index.ts#L49) or [cardano-addresses](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-addresses) for this.

```
echo addr1gqtnpvdhqrtpd4g424fcaq7k0ufuzyadt7djygf8qdyzevuph3wczvf2dwyx5u | ./cardano-address address inspect

{
"stake_reference": "by pointer",
"spending_key_hash_bech32": "addr_vkh1zuctrdcq6ctd29242w8g84nlz0q38t2lnv3zzfcrfqktx0c9tzp",
"pointer": {
    "slot_num": 24157,
    "output_index": 42,
    "transaction_index": 177
},
"address_style": "Shelley",
"spending_key_hash": "1730b1b700d616d51555538e83d67f13c113ad5f9b22212703482cb3",
"network_tag": 0 }
```

But that is a movement in an opposite direction, getting a pkh from address.